# Алгоритм кратчайшего пути  и расчета времени в Московском Метрополитене

Tags: графы, алгоритм

Здравствуйте, интересует реализация алгоритма расчета кратчайшего пути в метро. В голове алгоритм есть, но реализовать пока толкого не получается. Буду крайне благодарен за исходники или подсказки на эту тему.
Спасибо!

Comment: Расскажите нам, как вы видите алгоритм "в голове", а мы постараемся помочь в реализации. Вообще, задача сводится к поиску кратчайшего пути на взвешенном ориентированном графе, где веса - расстояние между станциями или время пути между ними.

Comment: В голове сумбур, даже незнаю как описать.
Взять массив каждой ветки, идентифицировать его станциями, указать где они пересекаются, а дальше пока остановился.

Comment: Не-не-не, всё не просто. Вы должны учитывать время пересадок и расписание поездов. Это не просто поиск кратчайшего пути в графе.

Представьте себе, что из `A` в `B` можно доехать за 1 минуту прямо, но метро по этой линии ходит раз в полчаса. А можно с пересадкой через `C`, поезда из `A` в `C` и из `C` в `B` ходят каждые пять минут, и дорога занимает по три минуты. Тогда оптимальный маршрут зависит от того, скоро ли придёт прямой поезд.

Comment: Да, сразу видно, кто про метро только в книжках читал :D

Comment: По-моему, если учитывать расписание, надо найти все маршруты до конечной станции, а потом рассчитать время каждого маршрута исходя из расписания движения поездов... Ах да, ещё же есть время между переходами со станции на станцию :)

Comment: @tabby_cat: учитывая наличие в ДС кольцевой линии, таких маршрутов бесконечно много, так что придётся «рубить» деревья, превышающие текущий оптимум.

Comment: @VladD, можно ли сформулировать эффективный ряд ограничений из конфигурации метро, которые выполнялись бы всегда? Например, нет смысла пересаживаться на кольцевую больше 4 раз или не возвращаться назад по своей линии?.. что-нибудь эдакое :)

Comment: @tabby_cat: Ух вы и задачи задаёте... Сходу не скажу, надо подумать. Если поезд по кольцевой идёт медленно, возможно, выйти и проехать кусок пути по хорде, чтобы попасть на «предыдущий» поезд, идущий по кольцевой, будет предпочтительным алгоритмом. Возвращаться по своей линии, кажется, никогда не пригодится, т. к. «петлю» можно просто выбросить (но я не поручусь). Наверняка для _конкретного_ метрополитена можно придумать хорошую эвристику, но это надо вдумчиво анализировать расписание.

Comment: Мне кажется для задачи поиска кратчайшего пути между двумя точками простой перебор всех возможных маршрутов (ветвимся, т.е. делаем новый маршрут как копию старого в пересадках) вполне подойдет. 

Просто надо отмечать прямо в графе, что данная станция уже была посещена данным маршрутом и отбрасывать такой маршрут.

Answer (score 1):

Если время поджимает, то я рекомендую вам выбрать простейшую модель, а именно:

1. Граф неориентированный.
2. Длины всех ребер одинаковые.
3. Пересадки происходят мгновенно, группы пересадочных станций "склеены".

### Подготовка

Тут надо будет поработать руками. Берете схему метро и нумеруете станции от 0 до N - 1, где N -- общее число станций, порядок не важен. Потом записываете все перегоны между станциями, которые и будут ребрами нашего графа. Каждый перегон описывается парой чисел. Записываете всю эти данные в файлик. Формат файла можно выбрать такой:

```
<число вершин> <число ребер>
<начало ребра 1> <конец ребра 1>
...
<начало ребра N> <конец ребра N>
```

### Представление графа в памяти

В этой задаче подойдет представление в виде списков смежности, а так как граф в процессе не модифицируется, то реализовать его можно через `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

### Загрузка графа

Загрузить граф из файла можно так:

```
std::ifstream data('graph.txt');
int n;
data >> n;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> graph(n);
int e;
data >> e;
for (int i = 0; i < e; ++i) {
    int a, b;
    data >> a >> b;
    graph[a].push_back(b);
    graph[b].push_back(a);
}
```

### Поиск расстояний

Из-за того, что все ребра графа имеют одинаковую длину, кратчайшие расстояния в нем можно искать поиском в ширину. По ссылке http://e-maxx.ru/algo/bfs есть реализация.

Answer (score -1):

[Топологическая сортировка](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/topological_sort) +

A - Матрица смежности. B - матрица того
же размера, что и А

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  for (int k = i + 1; k < N; ++k)
    for (int j = k + 1; j < N; ++j)
      if (a[i][j] > a[i][k] + a[k][j])
      {
        a[i][j] = a[i][k] + a[k][j];
        b[i][j] = k;
      }
```

В итоге, А - матрица кратчайших расстояний, B - матрица восстановления путей

Comment: Хотел бы я посмотреть на лица пользователей Яндекс.Метро, где использовался бы такой подход.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, уверен, что подход иной (скорее всего какая-то разновидность волнового алгоритма), но думаете лица успеют вытянуться (там всего 190 станций)?

Comment: Если можно, расписать как все это изобразить кодом на C/C++, курсовая горит( Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: @Aleksey-cda: Где ж вы раньше-то были? Вы взяли себе довольно сложную курсовую, за 5 минут вам её никто не напишет, а больше времени немногие захотят потратить. Вы бы сначала алгоритм точно придумали и описали.

Comment: @rekrut, почитайте внимательно, что такое топологическая сортировка. Она не дает кратчайших расстояний, даже если все ребра единичной длины.